# Setting View>Thread>Unread is not stored?

Tags: thunderbird

Setting View>Thread>Unread for a newsgroup works as expected: only unread articles are shown. However, if I move to a different newsgroup, and return to the original newsgroup, the setting is reset to View>Thread>All. What is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by a complete reinstall of thunderbird.